# What role does an asterisk serve in Backus–Naur Normal Form?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, formal-grammars, parsers, syntax

Suppose that you were reading some production rules for a [context-free grammar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_grammar) in [Backus–Naur Normal Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form)

What does the asterisk (`*`) mean?

In the example below, what is the difference between `<fun-def*>` and `<fun-def>`?

```
<program> ::= <fun-def*> int main(void) { <block> }

<block> ::= { <var-def*> <statement*> }

<fun-def> ::= void <var-name> ( <parameters> ) { <block> }
            | <type> <var-name> ( <parameters> ) { <block> }
        
<var-def> ::= <type> <var-name> ;
           | <type> <var-name> { <expression> } ;
           | <type> <var-name> = <expression> ;
```

Answer (score 2):

I have never seen this syntax before, but most likely, `<var-def*>` is a typo for (or unusual way of writing) `<var-def>*`.  A common extension of BN is to use the `*` operator from regular expressions.  In other words, `<var-def>*` represents 0 or more instances of `<var-def>`.

This does not increase the expressive power of BNF and is just syntactic sugar.  Of course we could have created a rule `<var-defs> ::= | <var-def> <var-defs>` and then used `<var-defs>` in place of `<var-def*>`.  But sometimes it is convenient to be able to use the more concise syntax, without having to create extra non-terminals and rules to represent repetition.